# Best way to set Java CLASSPATH variable, and why?

Tags: java, environment-variables, classpath

I encountered these questions while using Weka but this is a general question.

When I try to make a call from command prompt like

```
java weka.classifiers.trees.J48
```

it gives an error, whether I'm in the weka.jar folder or not. When I try to create a variable in System Enviroments named `CLASSPATH` and give it the value `"C:\Program Files\Weka-version-number"` it is still the same. But when I change the value to `".;C:\Program Files\Weka-version-number"` it is working. I didn't find that `" .; "` thing by research, that was by chance, and I researched again and couldn't find.

- Why is it working
- Should I do it
- What is the best way for setting classpath?

For example I couldn't set that by command:

```
java -classpath "...destination..."
```

How should one deal with enviroment variables? And so on...

Thanks.

**Edit:** I figured it out. That was not about `" .; "` thing, I didn't close the command prompt and open again, which looks like I should.(I guess it is reading those variables only at the beginning.) Now it is working when the `CLASSPATH` variable is `C:\Program Files\Weka-3-6\weka.jar` . Thanks.

Comment: well yes you need a ';' (but you don't need a '.' preceding the semi-colon) to separate different classpath values (i.e. I have several classpath values, for Python etc). And I'd say setting classpath values in environment variables like you have done is the best way

Comment: The best way to do it is most likely **not** via an environment variable as, unless this is a user specific variable and that user is a daemon user only running that application, setting it globally will cause you issues when running other Java applications. One way is to write a script that sets the variable and kicks off the process. The best way is to create an `.jar` correctly, that sets the classpath in the manifest.

Comment: I haven't set it at all since about 1998.